# Android cannot resolve enum value

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, enums

I've got this resources I want to use in a view.

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="ChipView">
    <attr name="chip_owner" format="enum">
        <enum name="p1" value="0"/>
        <enum name="p2" value="1"/>
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Also, I have a java enum to map this to

```
public enum Player {
    P1, P2;

    /**
     * Returns the opponent of this player
     *
     * @return the opponent of this player
     */
    public Player opponent() {
        if (this == P1)
            return P2;
        else
            return P1;
    }
}
```

But when I add my view to the corresponding layout, it cannot resolve the label for the enum value :

```
<spacebar.backgammoid.ChipView
    android:id="@+id/c4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:chip_owner="p1" /> <!-- Here -->
```

Android studio tells me :
Cannot resolve symbol 'p1'
Validates resource references inside Android XML files

I tried cleaning and rebuilding my project, without succeeding, also, I tried to add the ressource like this:

```
<resources>
<attr name="chip_owner" format="enum">
    <enum name="p1" value="0"/>
    <enum name="p2" value="1"/>
</attr>
<declare-styleable name="ChipView">
    <attr name="chip_owner" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

But neither that did what I expected.

Am I doing something wrong ? I found some questions about this subject, but none of them seem to have had any problem to make android resolve the label.

---

### EDIT

This is added as part of the question, because it is not really an answer.

**This issue solved itself when I accessed the enum programmatically for the first time**:

```
if (attrs != null) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ChipView);
    int player = a.getInt(R.styleable.ChipView_chip_owner, 0);

    if (player == 0)
        this.setOwner(Board.Player.P1);
    else
        this.setOwner(Board.Player.P2);

    a.recycle();
}
```

Now, if I remove this code, it continues to be able to resolve p1, so **something was permanently changed on the backstage**.

So, the question is pointless as it was formulated, but still I'd like to know **why was it failing and what change did I trigger by accessing the value from the class** (The value appeared in the auto-completion as soon as I accessed the attributes) with

```
context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ChipView);
```

So in order to reproduce this you have to:

1. Create a view, add an enum attribute
2. Use any value of this attribute in a layout (should fail)
3. Rebuild the project as many times as wanted (should still fail)
4. Access the enum from the View constructor (should stop failing)

**If this doesn't reproduce the problem, then my question is pointless and can be safely deleted**

By the way, I'm running :

- android-studio 1.2.2
- gradle 2.2.1
- oracle JDK 1.8.0_45
- Ubuntu 15.04_amd64

Comment: do you have `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your layout ?

Comment: Yes, also app:chip_owner is suggested by autocompletion and doesn't cause any error

Answer (score 0):

When java says "Cannot Resolve", it usually means that the point reference to that Variable doesn't exist, or has been incorrectly referenced.

What I suggest, (might work), is to ensure that all references to "P1" (from the Enum), is set to "P1" and not "p1". And do the same for "P2", this might solve the issue.

Also, if you like have a look at this: [Variable Structuring Help.](http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html)

Hope this helps.